# can neural network learn from error of its input not output

Tags: neural-network

Suppose we have a network that accepts 2 inputs : a signal from a sensor and a desired value. It outputs some control value. Can it learn to minimize difference on its inputs ?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEtzm.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the cost function to depend on difference of the inputs. However, since the neural network cannot influence the inputs it cannot minimize them.